# error LNK1104 libcpmtd.lib

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am trying to compile a project in VS2015 preview, & am getting an error LNK1104, can't find libcpmtd.lib. 
I'm using windows 7, & compiling Multi-threaded debug.

anyone run into this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I had a same problem while building my project with gtest.
I think it is a VS 2015 bug... :-)
Add the library directory to your project settings,
in my case, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib".
It works for me. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the problem was that I had the Platform Toolset under Project->Properties->General set to Visual Studio2013 (v120). Changed it to Visual Studio 2015 (v140) and it worked fine. Hope it helps :)