# C++ Runtime component(Universal Windows) project build error "LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'LIBCMT.lib'"

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, uwp, libyuv

I create C++ Runtime component(Universal Windows) project which a  reference to libyuv.lib (a google library). After I set the reference and build for x64, and I got an error "LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'LIBCMT.lib'". But In another visual C++ console project (win 32), I set the same reference to libyuv.lib library. It works. Please help me resolve the issue. Any help/comment will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Josh

Comment: Seems like libyuv.lib is built for native Windows, not for Universal Windows. So you cannot add libyuv.lib to your application if your application targets Universal Window. But you can use it in your native Windows console projects.

Comment: Thanks Werner. Yes I can use it in console app, but can't use it in Visual C++ windows runtime component project which will be called by mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue while using cURL for HTTP methods. UWP app with a C++ library in which cURL methods were implemented. The same **cannot open file "LIBCMTD.lib"** issue came up.

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32692730) by @thomas kim worked for me.

> Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General ->
>   Additional Library Directories and add the path: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64

Comment: Shouldn't UWP app link against MSVCRT , and not LIBCMT?